# How to display the camera in the app using the camera2 library?

Tags: android, image, camera, imageview, android-camera2

I am trying to show the camera view on the screen. I struggle using the camera2 library correctly. Here is the code:

1. This code prepares a display:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mCameraView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
       // More to come
   }
   ```
2. This code prepares a callback for each image received:

   ```
   ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(100, 100, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 50);
   imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new 
       OnImageAvailableListener() {
           @Override
           public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
               Log.i(TAG, "New image received");

               Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
               // Why this line returns null?
               ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
               byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
               buffer.get(bytes);
               Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);

               // When I get the new image from the camera, I display it in the app
               mCameraView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               image.close();
           }
       }, new Handler()
   );
   ```
3. This code opens the camera:

   ```
   mManager.openCamera(mManager.getCameraIdList()[0], new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {}

       @Override
       public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {}

       @Override
       public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
           try {
               // See below
           } catch (Exception exception) {
               throw new RuntimeException(exception);
           }
       }
   }, new Handler(getMainLooper()));
   ```
4. This code (inside `onOpened`) links the callback with the opened camera:

   ```
   camera.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(
       imageReader.getSurface()),
       new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session){
               try {
                   CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(
                       CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                   captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
                   cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureBuilder.build(),
                                new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {},
                                handler);
               } catch (CameraAccessException exception) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(exception);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {}
   }, null);
   ```

In the `MainActivity.java` file I link the 4 code snippets together. The
result is that `onImageAvailable` gets continuously called. However, nothing is displayed in the `mCameraView`. **Why**?

Comment: This won't answer your question but I will say that Camera2 Api is completely broken. Some phones it works ok but for any Samsung phone and some others you will find some very strange and unpredictable behaviors, so I would advise you to use the regular/old camera api. It is technically deprecated but that API is the most reliable and it isn't going anywhere. One thing you could try though with this is to write that image captured to a file, then attempt to display it through the file instead of decoding the byte stream.

Comment: @Devsil, maybe you know the reason why `ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();` returns **null**?

Comment: I don't know the answer as to why really. I do know that I have seen the same behavior on certain devices but the implementation will work on others. For example, when I was building a new Camera activity with the Camera 2 APi a while back I had a very functional camera with a lot of features and it worked great on my Pixel and Pixel XL, but when I went to run the same code on a Samsung S6 it didnt work at all or certain features were wonky. After investigating with a few other phone (mainly samsung) I decided to abort because certain manufactures evidently dont implement CameraAPI2 correctly